# Combine two jagged lists into one

Tags: c#, concatenation, jagged-arrays

Im having two jagged lists.

First one:

```
List<List<string>> firstList = new List<List<string>>();

{ dd ff }
{ dd ff }
{ dd ff }
```

Second one:

```
List<List<string>> secondList = new List<List<string>>();

{ gg hh }
{ gg uu }
{ hh uu }
```

Im having a problem with combining both lists into one like this one:

```
{ dd ff gg hh }
{ dd ff gg uu }
{ dd ff hh uu }
```

Any Concatenation attempt resulted in just adding `secondList` elements like another `firstList` rows like this:

```
{ dd ff }
{ dd ff }
{ dd ff }
{ gg hh }
{ gg uu }
{ hh uu }
```

Would appreciate any help with this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Zip extension method that is a part of the `System.Linq` namespace. Tuples can be used to associate values form both lists. Or you can just `Concat` inner lists.

```
var list1 = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "dd", "ff" },
    new List<string> { "dd", "ff" },
    new List<string> { "dd", "ff" },
};

var list2 = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "gg", "hh" },
    new List<string> { "gg", "uu" },
    new List<string> { "hh", "uu" },
};

var result = list1.Zip(list2, (l1, l2) => Tuple.Create(l1, l2)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try to use it!

Answer (score 3):

You can using [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) to do that to concatenate the corresponding sub-lists.

```
var combined = firstList.Zip(secondList, (f,s) => f.Concat(s).ToList()).ToList();
```

Note that if the two lists contain a different number of sub-lists the result will only have as many as the shorter of the two lists.

Comment: Actually, I feel that this is the best answer... I also learned new thing from you: `Zip`. :)

Answer (score 1):

The important idea here is you have to concat *each element* of the list rather than concatting the two lists.

1. Concat each element:

   ```
   { dd ff gg hh } //each element dd ff is concatted with gg hh
   { dd ff gg uu }
   { dd ff hh uu }
   ```
2. Concat the lists:

   ```
   { dd ff }
   { dd ff }
   { dd ff }   //elements from the 1st list
   ----------- concated with
   { gg hh }   
   { gg uu }
   { hh uu }  //elements from the 2nd list
   ```

You could `Concat` each element of the lists (which have to have same number of elements or the second one *more* number than the first) like this:

```
List<List<string>> finalList = (from x in firstList
                                join y in secondList
                                on firstList.IndexOf(x) equals secondList.IndexOf(y)
                                select x.Concat(y).ToList()).ToList();
```

Or any other way to feel like to do it.

Comment: Thanks! Will try to use it!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just loop through the first list and add the elements from the second list.  For example:

```
var list1 = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string> { "dd", "ff" },
    new List<string> { "dd", "ff" },
    new List<string> { "dd", "ff" }};

var list2 = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string> { "gg", "hh" },
    new List<string> { "gg", "uu" },
    new List<string> { "hh", "uu" }};

for(var j = 0; j < list1.Count(); j++)
{
    list1[j].AddRange(list2[j]);
}
```

Comment: Might as well use `list1[j]` instead of `list1.ElementAt(j)`.