# Multiple List<double> to Jagged Array C#

Tags: c#

I have 3 lists which their values are obtained dynamically

```
List<double> input = new List<double>();
List<double> time = new List<double>();
List<double> censor = new List<double>();
```

How can I convert/combine to `double[][]` as the example below in an efficient way?

```
double[][] example =
{
    //             input  time censor
    new double[] {   50,    1,    0   },
    new double[] {   70,    2,    1   },
    new double[] {   45,    3,    0   },
    new double[] {   35,    5,    0   },
    new double[] {   62,    7,    1   },
    new double[] {   50,   11,    0   },
    new double[] {   45,    4,    0   },
    new double[] {   57,    6,    0   },
    new double[] {   32,    8,    0   },
    new double[] {   57,    9,    1   },
    new double[] {   60,   10,    1   },
};
```

Comment: I assume you are confident that the lists are all the same length?

Comment: See [Combine two jagged lists into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076239/combine-two-jagged-lists-into-one)

Comment: @Chris, yes, all the list have the same length but this length is unknown until some event occurs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this

```
List<double> input = new List<double>();
List<double> time = new List<double>();
List<double> censor = new List<double>();

var results = new double[input.Count][];

for (var i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
   results[i] = new []{ input[i] , time[i] , censor[i] };
```

Comment: I think this has two advantages: (1) It's efficient and (2) it's understandable at a glance. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Linq appraoch

```
double[][] example = input.Select((x, i) => new []{ x, time[i], censor[i]}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of Zip :

```
    List<double> input = new List<double>() {1,2,3} ;
    List<double> time = new List<double>() {10,20,30};
    List<double> censor = new List<double>() {100,200,300};

    var result = input.Zip(time, (i, t) => new double[] {i, t})
        .Zip(censor, (x, c) => x.Append(c).ToArray())
        .ToArray();

    // result is  :
    // {{ 1, 10, 100}, 
    // { 2, 20, 200}, 
    // { 3, 30, 300}}
```